# Can I make my post.php save the data permanantly?

Tags: php

For my website you can visit here at http://desire.site88.net at the very bottom you will see my form. When you finish with the form and press submit the form submits the data to desire.site88.net/post.php . What I'm curious is how do I make it permanent? When the user submits data to post.php I want it to stay there. Not looking for anything secure or unhackable, just something I can use to recruit members. Here is my code

```
<?php

$username = $_POST['username']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$message = $_POST['message']; 

// what it will say down below
echo $username. ' has an email of </br>'; 

echo $email. ' and wants to join because </br>'; 

echo $message. '</br></br>';
```

`<form method="post" action="test.php">
                                <div class="row 50%">
                                    <div class="6u 12u(mobile)"><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" /></div>
                                    <div class="6u 12u(mobile)"><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" /></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row 50%">
                                    <div class="12u"><textarea name="message" placeholder="Application" rows="6"></textarea></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="12u">
                                        <ul class="actions">
                                            <li><input type="submit" value="submit" /></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>`

Comment: Permanent for whom? That user sees the same thing permanently? _All_ users see that users thing permanently? You collect them for later? Persistence usually means writing to a database, but depending on what you really mean, it could also mean [saving to the session.](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

Comment: First: Welcome to StackOverflow! Check out [ask] and take a [tour]!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I want it to be permanent for me as I do want to collect them for later. I planned to make the php redirect right back to the original site. creating a database would be the only way? I'm not looking to make it strong, and secured. Just a quick way for me to recruit the people who apply.

Comment: So you want to collect a list for yourself - do you expect lots of people to sign up? If you don't, you could very easily save entries into a text file.

Comment: Lots of people most likely will apply. This is an event site to host tourneys for a huge guild in an online mmo game I play. We got tired of the struggle of being emailed so we figured this would be a quick fix. But the "save entries into a text file" is actually what I was looking for. Any help?

Comment: Don't try to shortcut if you think it will be too much work. In the long run it will work out better. Using a database makes it easily searchable by ID and much more. Any respectable site uses a backend DB to store user info. **Use a CMS then and it will take care of most that for you.**

Answer (score 0):

So reading your previous comment about looking for a simple way to collect data without the need for security, I recommend saving it in a text file for now, and maybe later using XML, which you can investigate into later.

code to save into a text file:

```
$filePath = $username."-".time().".txt";
$myFile = fopen($filePath, "w");
fwrite($myFile, ("username: ".$username."\n"));
fwrite($myFile, ("email: ".$email."\n"));
fwrite($myFile, ("message: ".$message."\n"));
fclose($myFile);
```

that code will save a file with a unique name each time it is saved, and it would be located in the same directory as your php page.

let me know if that worked for you or if you have any doubts :)

**Edited:**
Explaining first how the function fopen() works. Placing "w" in the second parameter means the function will create a new file with the information you give it, and if the file already existed, it will re-write it, meaning any previous information that existed in the file will be gone. For this reason, I made the $filePath unique, so that no overwriting happens. I will now go a bit further and include the logs in a new separate file that is outside the root folder for added security:

```
//++++ path obtained to your root folder
$root_directory_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
//++++ creating the path for the logs in a new folder outside
//++++ the root director
$filePath = $root_directory."/../my_logs/".$username."-".time().".txt";

//++++ starting the creation of the file
$myFile = fopen($filePath, "w");

//++++ inputing information into the file
$inputString = "username: ".$username."\n";
fwrite($myFile, $inputString);

$inputString = "email: ".$email."\n";
fwrite($myFile, $inputString);

$inputString = "message: ".$message."\n";
fwrite($myFile, $inputString);

//++++ closing the file / finalizing the creation of the file
fclose($myFile);
```

---

I visited your site and it seems you are having issues with the permissions that the site gives you. If you still wish to user text files inside the root directory, you can follow the code below, however be informed that anyone can view the users that are registered since the information is being saved in a subfolder of the rood directory, so I do recommend transitioning to a database that is secure:

```
$filePath = "/myLogs/".$username."-".time().".txt";
$myFile = fopen($filePath, "w");
fwrite($myFile, ("username: ".$username."\n"));
fwrite($myFile, ("email: ".$email."\n"));
fwrite($myFile, ("message: ".$message."\n"));
fclose($myFile);
```

Comment: blind leading the blind

Comment: @naomik I'd love to know why, I'm always open to learn something new :). If it's regarding security, he did mention that was not a factor in his equation. If he wanted it to be slightly more secure, he could save it in a file that is outside his root directory.

Comment: It is saving the information but just to make sure. I still need to add echo in that code right?

Comment: Well you're explaining almost nothing. What are common solutions to this problem? Typically this should be done using a database, but the file-writing option is a nice lo-fi solution. But then you use `w` mode without detailing its function. What's with the extraneous parentheses, too?

Comment: also Can I keep them all in one file?

Comment: @naomik I specifically didn't mention a database because he wasn't interested in it. I highly recommend a database, but since he specified he was not interested, I went along with something that might be practical to him. It is lo-fi, and I believed that is what he wanted, though I could have interpreted the question wrongly. I will however edit why I used "w", you are correct that I should have explained it better to him. Regarding the parenthesis, I thought it might be more visual and understanding to the user since I do believe he is new to php.

Comment: @Jayy Yes. What I recommend doing is saving it in a file outside your Root Directory since it is at least more secure. I will edit my code on top for you.

Comment: @Jayy I modified my answer again below, because I noticed that on your site you were having permission issues, meaning you couldn't save files outside your root directory.

Comment: Yeah spent 30 minutes trying to figure it out and I can't so I give up for now. But I'm actually having an issue getting the code to actually save the username email and message.

Comment: @Jayy in that case, it's easier to debug your problem by making the file you are sending the user to something simple: `<form action="test.php" method="post">`, and in test.php, try this code to see if it is actually being received: `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><?php echo "username: ".$_POST['username']."<br>";?></body></html>` And at least then you'll know if the information is passing through. If it is passing, then the error should be some other part of your code. Make sure to delete text.php and change your code back after debugging!

Comment: Yeah that alone did not print the username.

Comment: @Jayy so the problem is probably with the form code. Can you edit you post with everything between `<form action.... >..</form>`?

Comment: weird... seems fine. I can't be sure what the problem is, all I can recommend at this point is to try to narrow down the problem. make two separate empty files without any other code, see if a simple form works. If it doesn't work, and all the code is correct, maybe the free hosting doesn't allow the use of the post method, but that would be a bit strange if it already allowed php.